# Recycling within an existing activity vs Opening another activiy

Tags: java, android

Following the successful publication of my first app, I wanted to challenge myself to build an app that would teach a language. I built a prototype using App Inventor, and it basically featured a phrase, a button to play a recording, a button that would make a toast translation, and a next button.

As I've started writing this app, I've relied on the crutch of opening a new activity each time I press the next button. This is inefficient and frankly, stupid of me.

Would it be preferable to build a list/array of all the phrases, translations, and audio files in sequence, and simply update all the related views upon click? How would one keep track of the sequence if I wished the app to also has activities where the user inputs his own response to a question?

i.e. 4 phrase activities, followed by 1 question-answer activity, rinse and repeat.

Thank you for helping out a newbie.

---

EDIT ExerciseActivity added

```
public class ExerciseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String TopicKey = "topic";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String topic = intent.getStringExtra(TopicKey);

    TextView description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.phrase);

    **description.setText(FindExercise(topic, 0));**
```

I cannot get the setText to work by calling the topic/title of the exercise, i.e. Basics, because it is a string and not an Exercise. How can I access the list with a Title received from another activity?

```
}

public String FindExercise (Exercise[] exercise, int position){
    return exercise[position].description;
}

//Database for exercise 1 "Basics"
Exercise[] Basics = new Exercise[]{

        new Exercise("Ni hao", "Hello", "b1", "b1"),

};
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `Activity` will do for your app. You can use animations to notify the user that the question has changed instead of starting a new activity.

Consider using local storage (i.e. database). This will simplify storing, retrieving, and tracking the order in which your phrases are shown. Just add a flag that a phrase is already visited or not in order to know which phrase is coming next, and retrieve only the un-visited phrases.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've decided to use multiple lists with exercises, but I've run into a problem: How does one access the name of a list using a String title? I've updated my original question with the situation

Comment: Solved the issue by giving each exercise its own unique int reference, and then creating a hashmap of exercises using this intref